# IBM Bluemix : How to access the Dashboard view in the new console of IBM Bluemix

Tags: console, ibm-cloud, dashboard

I have been using the IBM Bluemix console, the new version lately. I am unable to find the Dashboard view as available in the classic version of IBM Bluemix console. Please help in identifying the Dashboard view in the new console of IBM Bluemix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/#all-items link to get a similar view. It shows all the apps and services in the selected space.

You can get to that page by logging in, selecting *Console* and then the *All Items* tab.

[image: All Items]

Comment: Hi @Frederic, I am unable to see any items in the All Items tab in the new console. However, I am able to see all the apps created in the space in the classic console's dashboard. Is there any settings to be added in order to view the apps in the new console??

Comment: No particular settings. I've added a screenshot to my previous post. Pointing the obvious I know, but make sure you are looking at the same org/space in the new console vs. classic console, clear your cache, try another browser.

Comment: Please let us know if you continue to experience issues so that we can look at any other solutions.